# MVC Mailer For Sending Register Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvcmailer

I am trying to use MVC mailer using Razor engine to send out an email when the user has registred for a service.

1. I would like to know how to call the controller for MVC mailer from a function which is written in another Controller say RegisterController.
2. I need to pass in the Model for Email say WelcomeModel as well as the Email address for the user.
3. How can I test whether the email is being sent.

Appreciate responses!!!

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Comment: Hi,I have gone through this page and created the MVC Mailer.

Comment: That page answers all of your questions. See sections: 1) **Send Mail from Controller** 2) **Pass Data to Mailer Views** 3) **Configure SMTP Client**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Also, please let us know what you've already tried and what you're getting stuck with specifically so we can better help!

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks .Will go thru both links and update.

Comment: Hi,I have gone through the links and successfully able to dump the emails to a local directory.But when I try to configure smtp credentials it errors our telling "Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."Could you please help...